# Track How many Copies of a Google Sheet Have Been Made?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm sharing a Google Sheet with people but forcing them to make their own copy using the /copy URL trick (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/copy). Is there a way to track how many copies of the sheet have been made this way?

Comment: You might be able to by looking in Drive API activity.

Comment: @Cooper when making a copy, you make a copy on your drive, not the drive of the owner of the original file. Basically you're creating a copy on your own drive, so unless I'm very wrong, that will affect your drive api activity, not the author's.

Dave I don't think there is a way to track that

Comment: This [resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/create#Create) suggest that some information about copying is available.

Comment: This [one](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/actor#Actor) suggests that some information about the user might be available.  I'm not interested in taking it any further myself.

Comment: @cooper I believe this /copy trick uses this API call: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy At the moment, I'm just looking for a way to count how many times the link is used.